# The only female/woman among the police officers

Tags: grammar

(A group of police officers is gathered.)

Ben was talking with Gina, the only female/woman among the police officers.

Is both "female" and "woman" natural to use in this sentence?

Comment: Although some people use the noun "female" to refer to a woman, many people find it grating or even offensive, since this is more often done with animals than with people.

Answer (score 3):

Female and woman *can* be interchangeable, but it depends on the context. "Female" is a less personal term than "woman".

As you are talking about police officers, consider some text from [this article](https://www.gov.uk/government/speeches/women-in-policing) about the British Police force. Throughout the article it uses both terms, but notice how they are used differently in this block of text:

> Today, there are over 35,000 **female officers** in England and Wales, representing 28.2% of all police officers and up from 25.7% in 2010.
> The proportion of **women** in senior ranks of Chief Inspector and above has also risen in the past five years.

When speaking about them as "officers", it uses 'female', but when speaking about the as individuals it uses 'women'.

I think the most natural way to express your example would be:

> Ben was talking with Gina, the only female police officer in the (force/division?).

Using her name 'Gina' is personal. Calling her a 'female police officer' is using her job title and seems consistent with the article I quoted above.